# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'Matomo.initTracker')]

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, sdk, matomo

I want to implement Matomo in my react native app. I installed this library and followed the instructions https://github.com/BonifyByForteil/react-native-matomo#include-the-library. For the IOS it works perfectly but for Android I get the following problem [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'Matomo.initTracker')]. Does someone know the reason for this? The dependecy is installed correcly on the Android Build.